# How do I configure fontconfig to map a font name with a hyphen?

Tags: fonts

I'm having trouble with fontconfig recognizing the `ui-monospace` font that several websites (including Github and Stack Exchange sites) have recently started using. Firefox doesn't yet have that special CSS reference to system fonts (see [FF bug 1226042](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1226042), the [draft spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-4/#ui-monospace-def), and its [Can I Use entry](https://caniuse.com/?search=ui-monospace)), and FF is also fooled by fontconfig, which will satisfy any font with its default assignment for sans-serif.

As a workaround, I'd like to explicitly alias this font name to my preferred monospace font (which is [Panic Sans](https://github.com/chrissimpkins/codeface/tree/master/fonts/panic-sans), a tweaked DejaVu Sans Mono variant that nudges the underscore up a little), but since that's so obscure, this question uses [DejaVu Sans Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts#DejaVu_Sans_Mono).

My first attempt at this workaround doesn't work:

```xml
  <alias>
    <family>ui-monospace</family>
    <prefer><family>DejaVu Sans Mono</family></prefer>
  </alias>
```

Another attempt that has had more success for other fonts:

```xml
  <match>
    <test name="family"><string>ui-monospace</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="strong">
      <string>DejaVu Sans Mono</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
```

When I save that and flush my cache, it doesn't work:

```
$ grep ui.monospace ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
    <test name="family"><string>ui-monospace</string></test>
$ fc-cache -f
$ fc-match 'ui-monospace'
Carlito-Regular.ttf: "Carlito" "Regular"
$ fc-match sans-serif
Carlito-Regular.ttf: "Carlito" "Regular"
```

So that doesn't work. Here's the curious part: it works when I use a space instead of a hyphen:

```
$ sed -i 's/ui-monospace/ui monospace/' ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
$ grep ui.monospace ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
    <test name="family"><string>ui monospace</string></test>
$ fc-cache -f
$ fc-match 'ui monospace'
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
```

So it appears the issue is the hyphen. I don't see any documentation (or bug reports) suggesting this issue; the [fontconfig docs for `<string>`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html#AEN159) make no such note of illegal characters or how to escape them. I've tried defining it as `<string>ui\-monospace</string>` and `<string>ui&#45;monospace</string>` (and `&#x2d;`) but none of those worked.

How do I configure fontconfig to map a font name with a hyphen?

Comment: I think it is an issue with the shell, try again with `fc-match "ui\-monospace"`it works for me with fish shell.

Comment: Hyphen is not a special character for shells (if it were, `fc-match 'ui-monospace'` would have worked). That escape needs to be seen by _fc-match_, not the shell, as demonstrated by `fc-match "ui\\-monospace"` working.

Comment: Yes, the first part of my comment is wrong. I meant "command line interface" in opposition to API like pango... Anyway, it seems that `fc-match` needs the escaping. But the configuration should work with hypen in config file.

Comment: @NicolasGoy, it would be nice if you copy that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I put this snippet to the top part of my `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` and it works:

```xml
  <match target="pattern">
    <test qual="any" name="family">
      <string>ui-monospace</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same">
      <string>monospace</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
```

It has to be at the top, before the part that specifies which monospace I prefer.

Verified on GitHub and by `fc-match 'ui\-monospace'`.

Comment: Yes, but that sends a literal backslash in the match call. If you do `fc-match 'ui-monospace'` or `fc-match ui-monospace` or `fc-match "ui-monospace"`, it doesn't work. As noted by Nicolas Goy in a [comment to the question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1355091/260416#comment2347914_1355091), this is actually a bug in the `fc-match` command line. I additionally had some other font-rendering bug in my GUI apps that was solved by a reboot.

Comment: @AdamKatz several characters like `-` or `:` needs to be escaped because it has special meaning to fontconfig. The part after `-` is interpreted as `size` (but non-digits are ignored). However in the config file, it's already specified to test against `family`.